# How to fix this segmentation error?

Tags: c++, linked-list

the line that is provoking the error is commented beside, i am trying to remove a node from my linked list and when setting previous-> next to the node to be deleteds' next the segmentation error occurs.

```
void LinkedList::removeNode(int k)
{
    Node* pre = NULL; 
    Node* curr = NULL;
    Node* temp = NULL;

    pre = head;

    curr = head->get_next();

    for(int i =1; i<=length; i++)
    {

        if (i == k)
        {
            temp = curr->get_next();
            pre->set_next(temp); // this line causes segmentation error
            if(curr == tail)
            {
                tail = pre;
            }
            delete curr;
            break;
        }
        pre = curr;
        if(curr->get_next() != NULL)
        {
            temp = curr->get_next();
            curr = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Pleased provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you iterating thru linked list, but with some mystic `length` iteration limit, which isn't modified within node removal code...

Here a little bit optimized code:

```
void LinkedList::removeNode(int k)
{

    if (head == NULL)
        return;

    Node* curr = head; 
    Node* next = NULL;

    int i = 0;
    while ((next = curr->get_next()) != NULL) {
        if (++i == k) {
            curr->set_next(next->get_next());

            if (next == tail)
                tail = curr;

            next->set_next(NULL);
            delete next;
            length--;
            break;
        }

        curr = next;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the optimisation but with the new code am still getting a segmentation error, i know the 'k' value is correct and i know the list works as i have a print method which is printing them is order from head to tail. So I'm still a little confused as to why it will not remove the node

Comment: you used suggested code? at which line it seg-faulted?

Comment: eh, there is mistake! i updated the code. basically, it would go into endless loop without any conditions... i stumbled, how you could get it to seg-fault... did it seg-faulted at the very beginning, at ` while ((next = curr->get_next()) != NULL)` line? but that's possible only if `head` is null...

Comment: delete next if i remove it, it works fine ! but then i dereference the node